# How do I add precise border with longitude and latitude for any country using mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, google-earth, bing-maps

I have a plain image that I need to add international border with precise longitude and latitude but I have no experience with Mapinfo. How is it possible? Is there any way to import maps from Bing or Google Earth with that information?

Comment: Do you mean you need to generate features from your plain image? If yes, the process is called Digitization and you would be required to at least georeference your image before you could do so.

Comment: How can I do it with mapinfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer Mapinfo specific steps from the links below:

[Georeferencing (called Image Registration in MapInfo)](http://www.kxcad.net/MapInfo/MapInfo_Professional/MapInfow-13-04.html)

[Digitization](http://www.kxcad.net/MapInfo/MapInfo_Professional/MapInfow-26-49.html)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Kitex, effectively you need to georeference this.  If you know what the grid coordinates are of your MBR (min/max x and y), it is a very simple operation which can be performed in textpad.

If you're having issues, let me know the file name (of the image) and the grid coordinates and I'll tell you what you need to add to textpad to georeference it.

Comment: Thanks hairy ! I don't know mapping terms like georeferencing and I am just learning these terms. I have mapinfo professional and mapbasic.